# Indented comments in Python

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I was wondering if this is wrong or considered bad practice or anything:

```
def my_fuction():
    """This function does something."""
    pass

my_function()  # Yes I could write a comment here
    # But sometimes I need more space and make it clear
    # that a comment belongs to a certain part of my code
```

As you can see I indented my comment below the function call, in order to leave specific instructions / comments for this particular call. I indent it to make it clear that this comment belongs to this call of the code. PyCharm warns me that this is an unexpected indentation according to PEP8, but the code will execute.

Is this bad style and is there a better practice to make this kind of comment?

Comment: This is very much opinion-based since the compiler swallows it. Pep8 is nothing more than guidelines - it's not the law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this falls under [*Block Comments* part of PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments) , which advices -

> Block comments generally apply to some (or all) code that follows them, and **are indented to the same level as that code.** Each line of a block comment starts with a # and a single space (unless it is indented text inside the comment).

(Emphasis mine)

I believe the correct indentation for the comments would be -

```
# Yes I could write a comment here
# But sometimes I need more space and make it clear
# that a comment belongs to a certain part of my code
my_function()
```

And to me this looks better than having the first comment on the same line as the function call, and the rest below it.

Comment: Thanks. But my intention was to leave specific comments/ instructions for this particular call of the function.

Comment: Oh ok , sorry had miunderstood the question a little, but still I think it should come above the function call as given above. Though Like said in comments in question, PEP0008 is not a law, its just a guideline, its upto you if you want to follow it or now.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use editor-fold function to keep a part of code together and expand, like

```
# <editor-fold desc="Name of this block of code">
Here is my code
Here is also my code
# </editor-fold>
```